# Binding on a row of a list

Tags: wpf, list, binding, datagrid

I'm searching a way for making a binding of a datagrid colomn on a row of a list
looking for something like that in pseudo code:

```
                DataGridTextColumn colBuild = new DataGridTextColumn
                {
                    Header = "Custom Column Name",
                    Binding = new Binding("myList.elementAt(0)")
                };
```

I known this can looks strange but I'm looking for adding a variable number of custom columns on a datagrid in addition to fixed ones. And I don't know how to get data filled in those columns.
Can someone help me?

Comment: are you looking for this: `Binding = new Binding("myList[0]")`?

Comment: Maybe I go too fast.
I haven't find yet how to bind the columns field of the datagrid with my list of datagridcolumns.
Apparently datagrid.columns have no setter... how do i change that?

Comment: Amazing! i can't belive this is that easy! thanks dkozl